# gnome-control-center appearance tab broken

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center

When opening the appearance tab in gnome-control-center, it crashes.

Then it won't open again, until in dconf-editor I overwrite the value org.gnome.control-center.last-panel from "ubuntu", which is apparently the value for the appearance tab, to something else like "", "wifi" or "network".
This would probably be easier in terminal.

Anyone got an idea what is going on here?
Could I have accidentally uninstalled something that is required for this tab?

I really don't need this tab, but it is still kinda annoying when I accidentally click on it.

This appeared in /var/log/syslog after a crash:

```
Apr  1 15:18:57 qu gnome-control-c[8051]: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor' is not installed
Apr  1 15:18:57 qu kernel: [ 5373.136060] Rekeying PTK for STA 5c:83:8f:8e:43:8e but driver can't safely do that.
Apr  1 15:18:57 qu kernel: [ 5387.602416] traps: gnome-control-c[8051] trap int3 ip:7f21bdfb966f sp:7fff358a6830 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6800.4[7f21bdf7a000+8d000]
Apr  1 15:18:57 qu systemd[1252]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dcontrol\x2dcenter-8051.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Apr  1 15:18:57 qu systemd[1252]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dcontrol\x2dcenter-8051.scope: Consumed 2.459s CPU time.
```

This after another crash:

```
Apr  1 15:25:27 qu gnome-control-c[8530]: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor' is not installed
Apr  1 15:25:27 qu kernel: [ 5777.251051] traps: gnome-control-c[8530] trap int3 ip:7f35ab17d66f sp:7ffe0480cf90 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6800.4[7f35ab13e000+8d000]
Apr  1 15:25:27 qu systemd[1252]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dcontrol\x2dcenter-8530.scope: Deactivated successfully.
```

- Version: Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64
- PC: HP Pavilion Power Laptop 15-cb0xx
- CPU: Intel i5-7300HQ
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile

Comment: Is there anything in the log files that might explain the reason for the crash? From the description, it sounds like a programming error in Gnome Control Centre, but I'm unable to duplicate the issue on my 21.10 test machine 

Comment: I edited the question and added something that might help. Do I need gedit for the appearance tab work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need gedit for the appearance tab work?

Apparently you do. If `gedit` is installed, then you may have a broken `common` package. It can be reinstalled like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit-common
```

Otherwise, you may need to reinstall the entire `gedit` package

Comment: It works lol. I don't quite understand why `gnome-control-center` would need `gedit` for the appearance tab to work, but I guess I can't do anything about it. Thanks.